# Why is my footer element covering page content?

Tags: html, css, footer

Firstly, I am VERY VERY new to coding in HTML and CSS.  I've been studying for exactly a week now, and I thought I'd practice around to try and help me remember some of the elements, properties and attributes.  Therefore, the code you are about to witness may hurt your eyes, but any help on the matter would be greatly received.

I'm designing a website (which is very likely never to go live even its final form) and I started messing around with the footer element.  A bit later on, I discovered you can make a div element for a footer.  However, whichever method I use, it always ends up covering text on my screen.  It does stick to the bottom of the page until I scroll down, and it covers the body content at all times.  I'm aware it's likely due to the CSS code styling the body, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

I've kept it as a div for now, but if a footer would be better used then please do let me know.  I absolutely want to perfect whatever mistakes I'm making as soon as I encounter them.

```css
nav a {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.left-column {
  height: 40vh;
  flex: 50%;
}

.right-column {
  height: 35vh;
  flex: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#right-col-home {
  background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/bprblogassets/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/11165212/Power-Washing-Beginner.png);
  margin-top: 12em;
}

.nav-bar {
  border-width: 0em;
  border-color: ghostwhite;
  border-bottom: 0.15em solid gray;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0.8em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.second-body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 10em;
  padding-right: 10em;
  color: slategray;
}

.main-heading {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: slategrey;
}

.body-text {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}

.job-list {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}

.main-body {
  background-color: ivory;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  clear: both;
}

.question {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.answer {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.footer-bottom {
  background: #343a40;
  color: #686868;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Cleaning by Mark</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="main-body">
  <nav class=nav-bar>
    <span style="font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; color: slategray;">Commercial Cleaning</span>
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="second-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left-column">
        <h1 class="main-heading">FAQ</h1>
        <h2>Some frequently asked questions with answers:</h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2 class="question">What services do you provide?</h2>
        <h3 class="answer">A whole range of services is on offer, from patio and driveway cleaning to roof and conservatory cleaning! Feel free to check out the services offered on the 'Home' page. If you still have a question, or would like to enquire about another service,
          feel free to access the 'Contact' page and get in touch any time.</h3>
        <h2 class="question">What are your prices?</h2>
        <h3 class="answer">It's always difficult to provide an accurate quote without first assessing the job. However, Mark will happily provide a free no obligation quote - you may be surprised!</h5>
          <br>
          <h2 class="question">Are you able to clean rooves on houses?</h2>
          <h3 class="answer">Yes! Mark's reach isn't limited to bungalows, conservatories and annexes. With his state-of-the-art equipment, he will be able to clean all the moss and dirt from house rooves too!</h5>
            <h2 class="question">Do I need to provide anything?</h2>
            <h3 class="answer">Here at Commercial Cleaning, we will provide all tools and chemicals required to clean the job. However, there may need to be an access for water - this is more possible with larger jobs. But rest assured, there will be no cost to you - the
              cost of water will be deducted from your final invoice!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="right-column" id="right-col-home">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer-bottom">
    &copy; 2022 | commercialcleaning.com | Designed by Kieran|
  </div>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the code what I understand is the footer </div> don't have a starting tag. It's  above the body tag. I think u must try adding a starting <div> tag below  footer comment line.

Comment: Ah, yes, that appears to be an excess line of unwanted code which I had forgotten to delete; it was from a <div> tag which had existed but is no longer!  Thank you for pointing it out to me, I've now amended it.

Comment: FYI, tags are just text in a file. _Elements_ are what you see in the browser and often require two tags to render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your `vh` units, those are problematic in this instance because on smaller devices the excessive text may exceed the set `vh` and 'bleed' below the `footer`.

Then change your `footer` to `position: relative;` and set a `min-height: 100%;` on the `.second-body`.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

nav a {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 2em;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.left-column {
  height: 100%;
  flex: 50%;
}

.right-column {
  flex: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#right-col-home {
  background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/bprblogassets/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/11165212/Power-Washing-Beginner.png);
}

.nav-bar {
  border-width: 0em;
  border-color: ghostwhite;
  border-bottom: 0.15em solid gray;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0.8em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.second-body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
  color: slategray;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main-heading {
  font-size: 3em;
  color: slategrey;
}

.body-text {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}

.job-list {
  font-size: 1.0em;
}

.main-body {
  background-color: ivory;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  clear: both;
}

.question {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.answer {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.footer-bottom {
  background: #343a40;
  color: #686868;
  padding: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cleaning by Mark</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="main-body">
  <nav class=nav-bar>
    <span style="font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; color: slategray;">Commercial Cleaning</span>
    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
    <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="second-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="left-column">
        <h1 class="main-heading">FAQ</h1>
        <h2>Some frequently asked questions with answers:</h2>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h2 class="question">What services do you provide?</h2>
        <h3 class="answer">A whole range of services is on offer, from patio and driveway cleaning to roof and conservatory cleaning! Feel free to check out the services offered on the 'Home' page. If you still have a question, or would like to enquire about another service,
          feel free to access the 'Contact' page and get in touch any time.</h3>
        <h2 class="question">What are your prices?</h2>
        <h3 class="answer">It's always difficult to provide an accurate quote without first assessing the job. However, Mark will happily provide a free no obligation quote - you may be surprised!</h5>
          <br>
          <h2 class="question">Are you able to clean rooves on houses?</h2>
          <h3 class="answer">Yes! Mark's reach isn't limited to bungalows, conservatories and annexes. With his state-of-the-art equipment, he will be able to clean all the moss and dirt from house rooves too!</h5>
            <h2 class="question">Do I need to provide anything?</h2>
            <h3 class="answer">Here at Commercial Cleaning, we will provide all tools and chemicals required to clean the job. However, there may need to be an access for water - this is more possible with larger jobs. But rest assured, there will be no cost to you - the
              cost of water will be deducted from your final invoice!</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="right-column" id="right-col-home"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <div class="footer-bottom">
    &copy; 2022 | commercialcleaning.com | Designed by Kieran|
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has totally solved my problem.  I'm curious as to how vh units are problematic, providing you have the time to quickly answer?  Either way, my footer is now rooted to the bottom of the page without covering content and I've learned something new today.  Win-win!

Comment: @KieranHovell `vh` is problematic in this instance because you have a lot of text content on one side that has `height: 40vh;`, meaning when you reduce the height of the browser (under `40vh`) the content will fall underneath the `footer` because it's maintaining the `40vh` that it doesn't have room for, for example when you run the snippet without making it full page ~ `> 40vh`. [like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqiwM.png)

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense and I completely understand; a mistake I certainly won't be making again.  Once more, thank you for your time and the solution you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow-y:hidden;` to the .footer-bottom class.
It's pretty straight forwards — will prevent page overflow on a vertical axis.

**EDIT:** 
If this doesn't help, you could use section tags and pad these (which would be your better option). 
ie)

```html
<section title="Section1">
<!-- Apply padding to top and bottom of Section1 in CSS. -->
Content here
</section>
<section title="Footer">
<!-- Apply padding to top of Footer in CSS. -->
Content here
</section>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response, however this doesn't appear to have fixed it.  It still remains at the bottom of the page, although it covers content and doesn't scroll down with the rest of the body.

Comment: I haven't experimented with the section tag yet, but I'll certainly give that a go after some research.  Thank you for the suggestion!  I've made a comment in my source code to work it in ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks like your footer is set to have "absolute" position. When you do this, it's not taking into account anything that may be hidden behind it.

The way I usually remedy this is to add more margin to the content behind it - in this case, it would be extra margin in the bottom.

This way, the hidden content will have extra space to scroll further down, thus bringing the hidden content into view (above the footer).

EDIT: I think I was describing an issue which wasn't really your problem.

You can do "position: fixed" if you want the footer to be fixed in place, even with scroll (if you want to do that).

If you want to continue with "absolute" position, note that wherever the reference point of "bottom: 0" is is depending on the parent container, which I think is body in this case. If the container is "position: relative" (like if it was inside a div which you styled to have relative position), then it would take the bottom of that div.

So if your footer moves in an undesirable way when you scroll, it's because it's anchored to the bottom of the parent/container (which is position: relative). So you should address the parent - if you want the footer to always be at the bottom of the page, then the footer's anchor/parent should be at the bottom of the document.

Hope some of this information is helpful!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thank you so much for going into detail about the position property and its values!  It has helped me to understand them better, as well as giving me a better understanding of what was going wrong.  Between your information and Kameron's answer, I'm now in a position to sort the footer out properly and carry on learning.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added div tags to the  part. then created a footer with a different style sheet settings. I've also added the style reference into the html page but that just for ease of accessing it. The new footer settings in the style part is called #aFooter. This keeps the footer at the bottom of the page but not scrolling. It may be an idea to look at a script to keep the footer's div tag anchored to the bottom of the window element of the web page.

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Cleaning by Mark</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1">
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DM+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
            </head>
            
            <style>
        nav a {
            color: black;
            font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            padding: 12px;
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 80%;
            text-align: center;
            padding-left: 5em;
            padding-right: 2em;
        }
        .row{
            display: flex;
        }
        .left-column {
            height: 80vh; 
            flex: 50%;
        }
        .right-column {
            height: 35vh;
            flex: 50%;
            background-position: right; 
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        #right-col-home {
            background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/bprblogassets/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/11165212/Power-Washing-Beginner.png);
            margin-top: 12em;
        }
        .nav-bar {
            border-width: 0em;
            border-color: ghostwhite;
            border-bottom: 0.15em solid gray;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            background-color: ghostwhite;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 0.8em;
            margin-bottom: 2em;
        }
        .second-body {
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
            padding-left: 10em;
            padding-right: 10em;
            color:slategray;
        }
        .main-heading {
            font-size: 3em;
            color: slategrey;
        }
        .body-text {
            font-size: 1.0em;
        }
        .job-list {
            font-size: 1.0em;
        }
        .main-body {
            background-color: ivory;
            min-height: 400px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            clear: both;
        }
        .question {
            font-size: 1.7em;
            font-weight: bolder;
        }
        .answer {
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .footer-bottom {
            background: #343a40;
            color: #686868;
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            position:relative;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
            padding-top: 20px;
        }
        
            #aFooter {
        position: relative;
        min-height: 150px;
                bottom: 0px;
                left: 0px;
        }
        
        #aFooter-content {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        }
        
        #aFooter, #aFooter * {
        background: #343a40;
        }
        </style>    
            
        
            
            <body class="main-body">
            <div>
                <nav class=nav-bar>
                    <span style="font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: bold; color: slategray;">Commercial Cleaning</span>
                    <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                    <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                    <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
                    <a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a>
                </nav>
            
                
                
                <div class="second-body">
                
                    <div class="row">
                
                        <div class="left-column">
                            <h1 class="main-heading">FAQ</h1>
                            <h2>Some frequently asked questions with answers:</h2>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <h2 class="question">What services do you provide?</h2>
                            <h3 class="answer">A whole range of services is on offer, from patio and driveway cleaning to roof and conservatory cleaning!  Feel free to check out the services offered on the 'Home' page.  If you still have a question, or would like to enquire about another service, feel free to access the 'Contact' page and get in touch any time.</h3>
                            <h2 class = "question">What are your prices?</h2>
                            <h3 class = "answer">It's always difficult to provide an accurate quote without first assessing the job.  However, Mark will happily provide a free no obligation quote - you may be surprised!</h5>
                            <br>
                            <h2 class = "question">Are you able to clean rooves on houses?</h2>
                            <h3 class = "answer">Yes!  Mark's reach isn't limited to bungalows, conservatories and annexes.  With his state-of-the-art equipment, he will be able to clean all the moss and dirt from house rooves too!</h5>
                            <h2 class="question">Do I need to provide anything?</h2>
                            <h3 class="answer">Here at Commercial Cleaning, we will provide all tools and chemicals required to clean the job.  However, there may need to be an access for water - this is more possible with larger jobs.  But rest assured, there will be no cost to you - the cost of water will be deducted from your final invoice!</h3>
                    <BR><BR> <br> <br> <br><br> <BR>
                    <BR><br><br> <br><br><BR><br><br> <br><br>
        
        
                    </div>
        
                    
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="right-column" id="right-col-home">
                    This is right column.
                            </div>          
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div id="aFooter">
        <center> <h1>Footer</h1>
        <div id="header-content">   &copy; 2022 | commercialcleaning.com | Designed by Kieran| </div>
        <center>
        </div>
            
            </body>
```